# How do you put the current users role into a field on a standard object?

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm still new to developing in salesforce and i'm working on a trigger that will retrieve the current users role and insert it into the region__c field on Contact. It shouldn't replace the value that is there but should add to it and not produce duplicate values if users have the same role.

I have the code below but Im having trouble getting the name of the user's role. It gives me an Id value that i've stored in roleId but I can't get the actual name when i try to query User. The query is null. What am I doing wrong?

(the region__c field is a multiselect picklist which i've read has to have ';' between each item in the list. Thats why i have the for query at the bottom.)

```
trigger ContactRegionTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) 
{
        for (Contact cont : Trigger.new) 
        {
            Set<String> cr = new Set<String>();
            cr.add(cont.Region__c);
            String roleId = System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();
            String usrRole = [select id, name, userRole.name from user 
                                  where id =: roleId limit 1].UserRole.Name;
            system.debug(usrRole);

            cr.add(usrRole);
            system.debug(cr);

            /*for(integer i = 0; i < cr.size(); i++)
            {
                cont.region__c = cr[i]+';';
            }*/


        }      

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of items to note here:

- You're storing the result of your query in `usrRole`, but are then trying to use `userRole` in the debug
- The above might just be a typo, but beyond that, a query will return a list of objects. You'd need to index into the list to get a specific object instance before you can use dot-notation to get at an individual field
- You're trying to query users with an Id of a role, which will always return no results
- Queries inside of loops are a bad thing

Fixing those things, your example would look like this

```
// The user returned by System.userInfo isn't going to change.
// It's always the current user running the code.
String roleId = System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();

// My personal style is to use plural variable names for collections (list, set, map)
//   and/or add list/set/map to the variable name
// It helps in keeping track of variables and what they hold when you work on larger classes
//   or projects
List<User> usersList = [SELECT id, name, UserRole.Name FROM user WHERE UserRoleId =: roleId];

// listing for a single user
// assumes that usersList is not empty
system.debug(users[0].UserRole.Name);

// Having a list means you usually need to iterate over it
for(User u :usersList){
    system.debug(u.UserRole.Name);
}
```

That said, I don't think you should be querying the User object here. You're not trying to get all users with the given role, but rather figure out what the role name is. You'd want to query the `UserRole` object to get at that information directly.

```
String roleId = System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();

// While a query will _always_ return a list, in the case where a single row is returned
//   Salesforce will allow you to assign that to a single instance of the appropriate SObject.
// If the query returns anything other than exactly 1 row (no rows, 2+ roles), you'll get an error
// The safe way to go about this is to always store the result of a query in a list
UserRole singleRole = [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole WHERE Id = :roleId];
System.debug(singleRole.Name);
```

As far as avoiding duplicates goes, that's what a `Set` is good for.

```
for(Contact c :trigger.new){
    // For each contact, we want to start with a fresh set (i.e. don't let
    //   values from a previous contact bleed over into the next one(s) )
    // Declaring this variable inside the loop helps that, though you'd really
    //   only need to reinitialize the set, or call the clear() method
    Set<String> contactRegionSet = new Set<String>();

    // A multipicklist field is just a string, separated by semicolons
    // We can use String.split() to get each of the currently selected values as a list
    // The Set class contains addAll(), which can take a list
    contactRegionSet.addAll(c.Region__c.split(';'));

    // Add the current user's role into the mix
    // If it's already contained in the set, the set will not change
    contactRegionSet.add(singleRole.Name);

    // Finally, we can use String.join to reassemble the multipicklist value (with semicolons)
    // String.join() only takes a List, so we need to do some conversion
    // Lucky for us, a List can be constructed from a Set
    List<String> newRegions = new List<String>(contactRegionSet);
    c.Region__c = String.join(newRegions, ';');
}
```

Comment: That was too fast !!

Comment: Lots of great information you provided thanks a lot! Im getting an error code "Attempting to dereference a null object at ```contactRegionSet.addAll(c.Region__c.split(';'));```

Comment: @Tyler you will have to add a `null` check for that i.e. before splitting, check for `c.Region__c !=null`. You usually get that error when you are referring a `null` object.

Comment: ```UserRole singleRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Id = :roleId];``` fails if the users role isn't a picklist value in the Region field. If its not a value can i grab it before the query? right now i just avoided it with a try/catch block

Comment: @Tyler That query shouldn't fail because `roleId` is being pulled from `UserInfo.getUserRoleId()`. If you're running into a new problem, please make another question (and make sure to include the full error message and point out the actual line of code that the error tells you is the issue).

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/277937/how-to-fix-error-in-getting-and-setting-user-role-to-custom-field

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get your use case, but in order to get the Role Name you are trying to retrieve, you should replace this:

```
List<User> usrRole = [select id, name, userRole.name from user where id =: roleId];
```

With this:

```
List<UserRole> usrRole = [SELECT Name, DeveloperName FROM UserRole WHERE id =: roleId];
```

Comment: I didn't know UserRole was its own object, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following are the things you could do to solve your problem.

- The problem with your query is that you are querying on `User` object and filtering the `UserId` by `RoleId`, hence it won't return any records. Also, you don't have to query on User in for loop as current user will always be same.
- And to get the values separated by `;` i.e. as a value in multiselect picklist , you can use [string](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class's `join` method.
- To avoid duplicate values in the `;` seperated values, you can use [Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm).

So your code should be something like below

```
trigger ContactRegionTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) 
{
    Set<String> cr = new set<String>();
    //get current user id
    String userId = System.UserInfo.getUserId();
    //query on user to get role name
    User ur = [select id, name, UserRole.name from User 
                              where Id =: userId];
    string roleName = ur.UserRole.Name;
    for (Contact cont : Trigger.new) 
    {
        //create a set to avoid duplicates
        cr = new set<String>();
        //get existing values
        if(cont.Region__c !=null){
            cr.addAll(cont.Region__c.split(';'))
        }
        //add current role name
        cr.add(roleName);
        //update values seperated by ';'
        cont.Region__c = string.join(new List<string>(cr), ';')
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and added null value check!