# How to fix error in getting and setting user role to custom field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 7 picklist values in the Region field on Contact and im trying to set with user roles. But user roles have 10 options. One of the values is `<None Specified>` and i get the error code:

```
ContactRegionTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: 
List has no rows for assignment to SObject Trigger.ContactRegionTrigger: 
line 10, column 1
```

The other two values that aren't in the Region field on Contact give me `bad value` error. Is there anyways to use if/else to set the values before the query

```
trigger ContactRegionTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) 
{    
    //get the id of the current user
    String roleId = System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();

    //get the role name of the current user by using the roleId
**  UserRole singleRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Id = :roleId]; //Line10
    System.debug('single role name' + singleRole.Name);

    for(contact c: trigger.new)
    {
        Set<String> contactRegionSet = new Set<String>();
        if(c.Region__c != null)
        {contactRegionSet.addAll(c.Region__c.split(';'));}
        contactRegionSet.add(singleRole.Name);
        List<String> newRegions = new List<String>(contactRegionSet);
        c.Region__c = String.join(newRegions, ';'); 
    }


}
```

Now I tried this, and i can get around the error but doesn't fix my problem

```
trigger ContactRegionTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) 
{    
    //get the id of the current user
    String roleId = System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();

    try{

    //get the role name of the current user by using the roleId
    UserRole singleRole = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Id = :roleId];
    System.debug('single role name' + singleRole.Name);

    for(contact c: trigger.new)
    {
        if(singlerole.Name == null)
        {
             singlerole.Name = 'USNE';
        }
            else if(singlerole.Name == 'Executive Management')
        {
             singlerole.Name = 'USNE';
        }
            else if(singlerole.Name == 'US')
        {
            singlerole.Name = 'USNE';
        }
        Set<String> contactRegionSet = new Set<String>();
        if(c.Region__c != null)
        {contactRegionSet.addAll(c.Region__c.split(';'));}
        contactRegionSet.add(singleRole.Name);
        List<String> newRegions = new List<String>(contactRegionSet);
        c.Region__c = String.join(newRegions, ';'); 
    }
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        system.debug('Error code ' + e.getMessage())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that the user experiencing this issue has no role assigned.

That would cause `System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();` to return null, and in turn cause the query on `UserRole` to return no rows and give you that particular error.

Like I mentioned on your other question, assigning the result of a query to a single object instead of a List is a bit dangerous.

You could adjust your code to use a List here, but unless you specifically want to add "this user has no role" to `region__c`, then you could simply detect if `roleId` is null before running the query, and exit from the trigger early

ex.

```
String roleId = System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();

if(roleId == null){
    return;
}

// the rest of your code is unchanged
```

Alternative example, if you do want to add a value if a user has no role

```
String roleId = System.userInfo.getUserRoleId();
String roleName;

if(roleId == null){
    roleName = 'none';
}else{
    roleName = [<query on UserRole>].Name;
}

// and later in your code, you would modify things to use roleName instead of singleRole.Name
```

Comment: Oh okay, I thought the RoleId was just the User Id cause when i debugged it, it gave me a long string that resembled an Id. I didn't know it could be null but i combined the singlerole query with the rolename variable

Comment: @Tyler each SObject in Salesforce (that's things like `Account`, `UserRole`, `Contact`, etc...) has their own Id field. Ids are always either 15 or 18 characters long. The first 3 characters of an Id tell us (well, Salesforce) what SObject type the Id is for. Account Ids start with `001`, Case Ids with `500`, Opportunities with `006`, and so on. This is a strict separation, which lets us say things like "the Id for a `UserRole` will never be used as the Id of a `User` record".

Comment: You can (and do) find Ids for a given object on other objects (`UserRoleId` on `User` is a fine example), this is how records are related to one another, but the `UserRoleId` on a `User` record will never appear as the Id of a `User` record.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: how would you set a user's role name in a test class/

Comment: @Tyler I don't think you can set that directly. You'd need to update a user's role to one that contains the name that you're looking for. This is starting to head into "make another question" territory, but before you do that I'd suggest researching `System.runAs()` and `MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted`. That should get you pointed in the right direction (which I'd say is creating a user in a unit test, specifically for that unit test, which would allow you to set whatever role you wanted to use).

Comment: Yeah the ```mixed_dml_operation``` error is what im getting now, *sigh*. back to research. Thank you for your help